# how to disable view source in HTA applicantion

Tags: hta

I am working on HTML Application.So I want the code that will make my app to disable view source right click mouse in my app.Is there any way,please help me buddy

Comment: Some interesting properties can be found from [`<HTA: application>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Put contextmenu="no" in your HTA:APPLICATION header tag.  This disables the right click but it does not prevent someone who knows what they are doing from viewing the .hta file s it is plain text.  If you setup your users to open the .hta file via a shortcut, they will be less able to access the file that contains the code.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION 
 ID="myapp"
 APPLICATIONNAME="myapp"
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
contextmenu="no" 
>
```

Another option is to convert your hta to a .exe file.  Search for an app as there are a few and I've not tried them all.